# What's breaking suspend

Tags: suspend, wakeup

I have problem with suspend, every morning around 7am my computer wakeup. I do not wish it to do it because it sometimes drains my battery if not in charger. How do I fix this? :)

Ubuntu 13.10,
AMD proprietary drivers,
Using dejaup for backups..